# D3.js: Appending different amount of elements to group?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a graph representation but I'm not sure how to organize my data.

I currently have all the data bound to a group and have drawn the nodes.

The data includes the list of edges but I'm not sure how to draw them as each node has a different number of edges.

```
var group = svg.selectAll("g").data(dataset).enter().append("g);

//this works

group.append("circle")
     .attr(...).attr(...).attr(...);

//what to do here? when I call group, it will loop through each node ONCE and append a path
//but I need it to append edges.length paths for each pass

group.append("path")
     .attr("d", function(d,i){

        //example of 1 line
        lineSeg = [];
        lineSeg.push({"x":d.x ,"y":d.y});
        lineSeg.push({"x":d.edges[1].x ,"y":d.edges[1].y});

        return line(lineSeg);

     });
```

edit:

```
//just to add dom structure, my goal is for it to be:

g:
   circle
   path1
   path2

g:
   circle
   path1
   path2
   path3

g:
   circle
   path1

etc...
```

Lars linked to the relevant tutorial page. The key for me was the nested data joins

```
var td = d3.selectAll("tbody tr")
.data(matrix)
.selectAll("td")
.data(function(d, i) { return d; }); // d is matrix[i]
```

Comment: It sounds like you need nested selections. Have you seen [the tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)?

Comment: Thanks!, that was a really helpful link, added to edits.

Comment: please post as accepted answer